# Errors accessing List Items In SharePoint 2010

Tags: list

I have a SP2010 farm that works perfectly internal. The farm has 3 web apps on different ports, the one being naughty is on port :82 internally and it internal address looks like this: http://SharePoint:82

I publish this site using TMG 2010 with an external URL of http://portal.westhatch.essex.sch.uk

All seems to work fine until you try to access any list items or forms and I then get strange messages about the list does not exist or the form URL adds the :82 to the end of the external URL

I am seriously running out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: Do you have the alternate access mapping configured in central administration for your external zone?

Answer (score 1):

@Alan - It sounds like you are taking traffic from your TMG and routing it to the WFE on port 82.  If so, the default URL for that zone should be the URL that someone from the web would be accessing with.

I imagine you should have a zone configured for your external access as such:

External Zone

--http://portal.westhatch.essex.sch.uk (appears in the Public URL's page under external)

--http://sharepoint:82  (additional mapping to external zone)